grep pattern to find word in code
I'm looking for a grep pattern to find occurrences of a word in some code (Python, if it matters).
I want to ignore occurrences that are inside a longer word, inside strings, or inside comments (if possible).
So if I had this Python code:
Variable = 5
print(Variable)
MyVariablePlusOne = 6
description = "This is Variable"
# I love Variable

I want a way to grep for Variable that matches only the first two lines.

\< matches the beginning of a word, \> matches the end. You can't make a regex—especially a line-wise one like grep uses—that correctly handles comments and strings in all cases, but depending on your tolerance for false positives vs. false negatives, you can probably come up with a heuristic that filters most of the unwanted matches. Take that information and see what you can come up with.

Have you tried anything at all? Which part of this is giving you trouble? Do you know how regular expressions work? How grep works?

Even discounting that Python supports triple-quoted multiline strings (so determining whether a line is inside a string already goes beyond grep's line-based pattern matching), what is a variable? Something that is assigned to previously? That would exclude function arguments. Any word used where a value could be? But how do you determine whether the place something is used is suitable for a value without parsing the program (which is well beyond regular expressions of even the Perl kind)?

In any case, you'd be better off using Python's own ast parsing and using that to determine what's a variable than any regular expression

@muru I edited the question to identify my search target as simply a "word" instead of a "variable".

As muru says, you would need to use introspection (using the ast package) to do this correctly or implement your own Python language parser. I'm on the fence about whether this should be migrated to StackOverflow.  A Python program that analyzes the code with ast wouldn't be very long, but would be borderline off-topic for this site.

@muru I was not expecting it to support multiline content such as Python triple-quoted strings or java-style /* */ comments.

If the actual goal is to navigate source, something like ctags would be better suited for this. The tags file it produces can be supplied to an editor like Vim to support a range of actions on tags. For example, :ts myvar would present a list of symbols that equal myvar.

I can't think of a way to do this safely, especially not excluding mention of the variable name in strings and especially not when the code is python, so there are many ways of having a "string". Consider:
print("I love Variable")

but also
"""
I love Variable
"""

and so on. However, the main premise here seems to be "find the string Variable in my text file, but only if it is at the very beginning of the line, or or preceded by a non-whitespace and non alphanumeric character". If so, this should be a good start:
$ grep -P '(^|[^\s\w])Variable' file.py
Variable = 5
print(Variable)

The regex looks for either the beginning of the string ^, or (|) any character that is not in the character class (^[ ]). The class given is \s (whitespace) and \w (alphanumeric and -). The result is looking for all occurrences of Variable that are preceded by either the start of the line or a non-whitespace and non-word character.
You could extend this to avoid all lines whose first non-space character is a # with:
$ grep -P '^[^#]*(^|[^#\s\w])Variable' file.py
Variable = 5
print(Variable)

But this will really only serve as a starting point for your own later manual review.

Given "I want to ignore occurrences that are inside a longer word" you should probably have similar constructs after Variable as you have before it so the regexp doesn't match Variables, for example.

Using any POSIX awk given just the sample input you provided (I won't try to guess what other combinations of code structures you might have):
$ awk '
    { orig=$0; gsub(/"[^"]*"/,""); sub(/#.*/,"") }
    /(^|[^[:alnum:]_])Variable([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/ { print orig }
' file
Variable = 5
print(Variable)

The above assumes by "word" you mean any string of alphanumeric or _ characters, massage the regexp to suit if that's wrong.
With GNU awk for word boundaries you could use /\<Variable\>/ instead of /(^|[^[:alnum:]_])Variable([^[:alnum:]_]|$)/.
